# Use a non-coalescing parser in Axis2

Tags: java, apache-axis, axiom

Does anyone know how I can get Axis2 to use a non-coalescing XMLStreamReader when it parses a SOAP message?

I am writing code that reads a large base64 binary text element.  Coalescing is the default behaviour, and this causes the default XMLStreamReader to load the entire text into memory rather than returning multiple CHARACTERS events.  The upshot of this is that I run out of heap space when running the following code:

```
reader = element.getTextAsStream( true );
```

The OutOfMemory error occurs in `com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next`:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.XMLStringBuffer.append(XMLStringBuffer.java:208)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.XMLStringBuffer.append(XMLStringBuffer.java:226)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanContent(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:1552)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2864)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(XMLStreamReaderImpl.java:558)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.next(DisallowDoctypeDeclStreamReaderWrapper.java:34)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.wrapper.XMLStreamReaderWrapper.next(XMLStreamReaderWrapper.java:225)
    at org.apache.axiom.util.stax.dialect.SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.next(SJSXPStreamReaderWrapper.java:138)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.parserNext(StAXOMBuilder.java:668)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:214)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.SwitchingWrapper.updateNextNode(SwitchingWrapper.java:1098)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.SwitchingWrapper.<init>(SwitchingWrapper.java:198)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMStAXWrapper.<init>(OMStAXWrapper.java:73)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMContainerHelper.getXMLStreamReader(OMContainerHelper.java:67)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMContainerHelper.getXMLStreamReader(OMContainerHelper.java:40)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getXMLStreamReader(OMElementImpl.java:790)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImplUtil.getTextAsStream(OMElementImplUtil.java:114)
    at org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMElementImpl.getTextAsStream(OMElementImpl.java:826)
    at org.example.UploadFileParser.invokeBusinessLogic(UploadFileParser.java:160)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fairly easy to do. See the following section of the Axiom user guide:

http://ws.apache.org/axiom/userguide/ch04.html#factory.properties

Comment: Thanks for this - I managed to miss this in the documentation somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/SJSXP5.html, it is also available from Maven's central repository as

```
    <groupId>com.sun.xml.stream</groupId>
    <artifactId>sjsxp</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
```

if you place it on the classpath it will override the default impl

**UPDATE** There is another way. Create your own XMLInputFactory

```
public class XMLInputFactory extends
        com.sun.xml.internal.stream.XMLInputFactoryImpl {

    @Override
    public XMLStreamReader createXMLStreamReader(Reader reader)
            throws XMLStreamException {
        return super.createXMLStreamReader(reader);
    }
}
```

Create a file

```
META-INF/services/javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory
```

Note that javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory is the file name. Put your class fully qulified name in that file `test.XMLInputFactory`. See details at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html (Service Provider)

It will make Axis2 load your XMLInputFactory. Now you can intercept any method call and change parsing behaviour.

Comment: I want to change the behaviour of the existing parser to be non-coalescing rather than change the whole parser implementation.  If I had control of the XMLInputFactory, I'd call `factory.setProperty( XMLInputFactory.IS_COALESCING, Boolean.FALSE );`

Comment: I understand that, but that does not seem easy, that's why I offered an alternative, at least you could give it a try. Besides, "internal" StAX impl does not guarantee that it will behave like now in the next version

Comment: I used the properties file suggested by Andreas, but this seems like a good backup plan if I need to change something else on the XMLStreamReader that isn't covered by the other answer.